# VLC (Server) re-stream Security Camera Feed

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, h.264, surveillance

I purchased a [Swann Home Security DVR system](http://www.swann.com/s/products/view/?product=1382) and was hoping for some help on how to duplicate the streaming video on my server.

In order to get their web view (streaming video in the browser) to work, I had to install the following plugins:

```
HiDvrPlugin.dmg for mac.
Hidvrocx.cab for Windows.
```

I was originally thinking it was a sign of some form of DRM?  Maybe. Maybe not.

HTML wise, the following code is in the source of the safari version of the web view:

```
<embed pluginspage="SurveilClient.dmg" width="10px" height="10px" type="application/x-scplugin" id="MacDiv" style="height: 592px; width: 720px; left: 278px; top: 61px; ">
```

It seems to be the main display area.

Using wireshark, I am able to see that the video stream is on port 9000.  However, I have no idea what type of stream it is.  I've tried opening it in VLC with no such luck.

```
http://dvr_ip:9000
tcp://dvr_ip:9000
```

My hope was to do the following to redistribute the feed

```
vlc dvr_ip:9000 --sout h264-version-on-localhost:3000
```

TLDR; Trying to re-distribute a stream from a security camera (can't tell the format) using vlc (re-distribute via h.264 / HTML5).  Not sure how to accomplish this.  Is it possible that the software has some type of DRM that only the plugins can decode?

Comment: Any joy solving this? I've just hit exactly the same problem and using an IE ActiveX plugin just makes me shudder...

Comment: are you able to view the stream locally via VLC?

Comment: Many of these DVR solutions have some proprietary streaming going on that makes it only work with their player. Exporting the video should work as normal as they're in a standard container. Are the cameras you use IP cameras, or UNC?

Comment: try gstreamer instead

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already found that Swann uses a proprietary protocol on port 9000: [How do I find the video stream URL of my security DVR by myself?](https://superuser.com/questions/726942/how-do-i-find-the-video-stream-url-of-my-security-dvr-by-myself)

That said, the folks over at iSpy seem to have an extensive list of alternate places you might be able to find the stream in a normal format: http://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Swann